# How to implement the method reloadData of UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, datasource

MY PURPOSE:

I'm trying to make a view works like `UITableView` who has two properties as dataSource and delegate. I want this view works the same as `UITableView`

WHAT I DID:

I tried `UITableView` like this

```
UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 320)];
[self.view addSubview:tableView];
```

the tableView actually can show but without any data

then I changed to

```
UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 320)];
[self.view addSubview:tableView];
tableView.dataSource = self;
```

and implement the required methods of `UITableViewDataSource` protocol then the tableView show up with proper data.

MY QUESTION IS:

Does this mean the assignment somehow trigger method `reloadData`?

If so what does `reloadData` do under the hood? Does it init a new tableView with new data?

If not how to achieve the result that when I do `myView.dataSource = self` my view will show up with proper data?

Keep in mind that the assignment is after the init method.

Thanks

Comment: reloadData just reloads the data from the provided datasource. If you are assigning the tableview's datasource to self then this class must implement the methods of UITableViewDatasource Protocol in which you can handover the data to the table view to get it displayed in it. For reference of the datasource protocol check out this link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/index.html

Comment: In what method are you initialising this `tableView`?

Comment: those are apple delegates.reload data is a abstract method implemented by apple framework and it will call your  methods.it will call everymethod relatively.

Comment: add my purpose at first. hope that can help you to understand my question